# How is my Selenium script getting detected?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, automation, selenium-chromedriver

My simple Python script using Selenium is not working properly. My hypothesis is that it's getting detected and flaged as a bot. The only purpose of the script is to log in into zalando.pl website. No matter what I do, I get Error 403 ("Wystąpił błąd. Pracujemy nad jego usunięciem. Spróbuj ponownie później.").

I've tried various methods to resolve the problem. I've tried to simulate human behavior with sleep with random numbers (I've tried to use WebDriverWait as well). Also, I've been trying to solve the problem using options given to chromedriver, but it didn't help (I also edited string &cdc using hex editor). Exept all above, I tried undetected-chromedriver but it didn't help. Is there any way for my script to work?
Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'/chromedriver.exe')
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
print(driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;"))
driver.get('https://www.zalando.pl/login')


time.sleep(7)
username_entry = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login.email"]')
username_entry.send_keys("login@mail.com")
time.sleep(1)
password_entry = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login.secret"]')
password_entry.send_keys("password")
time.sleep(4)
button_entry = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sso"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/button/span')
time.sleep(2)
button_entry.click()
```

Comment: Can it be just that the site is down?

Comment: Are you sure the error is 304, and not 403?

Comment: Site is not down as I can login manually without problems. Yeah - it's the 403 error, my bad.

Comment: The script provided works fine for me. I'm using the [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) package, but I don't think that would make any difference.

Comment: @KamaleshS wow, are you able to login? if so, are u using proxy or sth?

Comment: @nekk I'm not using any proxy, I don't have valid credentials, but it entered all the values and clicked on the login button

Comment: @KamaleshS Okay so my problem is not wth entering the values. It's about login itself - my bot simply cannot login and I suppose its the reason of webdriver being detected